# Lack of run() method?

Tags: java

So I am reading 'Thinking in java'  book and I came across ColorBox program, changing color of boxes at random. However I noticed that there is a problem in running this code as if there wasn't run() method.

I highlighted it below with "/**HERE**/" :)

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.concurrent.*;
    import java.util.*;

    import static sun.misc.PostVMInitHook.run;


    class CBox extends JPanel implements Runnable {
        private int pause;
        private static Random rand = new Random();
        private Color color = new Color(0);
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(color);
            Dimension s = getSize();
            g.fillRect(0, 0, s.width, s.height);
        }
        public CBox(int pause) { this.pause = pause; }

        public void run() {
            try {
                while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    color = new Color(rand.nextInt(0xFFFFFF));
                    repaint(); // Asynchronously request a paint()
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(pause);
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                // Acceptable way to exit
            }
        }
    }
    public class ColorBoxes extends JFrame {
        private int grid = 12;
        private int pause = 50;
        private static ExecutorService exec =
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        public void setUp() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(grid, grid));
            for(int i = 0; i < grid * grid; i++) {
                CBox cb = new CBox(pause);
                add(cb);
                exec.execute(cb);
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ColorBoxes boxes = new ColorBoxes();
            if(args.length > 0)
                boxes.grid = new Integer(args[0]);
            if(args.length > 1)
                boxes.pause = new Integer(args[1]);

            boxes.setUp();
/**HERE**/  run(boxes, 500,400);
        }       
    }
```

I did change nothing, it is the exact code from book. They wanted to improve previous version including JApplet and there was method something like this:

```
public static void run(JApplet applet, int width, int height) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devil is in the details

```
import static sun.misc.PostVMInitHook.run;
```

That will allow you to call the `run()` as it's given.

It's not very nice though, since it's using `sun.*` packages, and you don't need to do it like that to get your program running. Probably a leftover from the past.

The more commonly used style would be something like

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    boxes.setSize(500, 400);
    boxes.setVisible(true);
});
```

Comment: I am using Intellij IDEA and there wasn't this package. I must have accidentally add it using Intellij suggestions. So actually it is not working properly without 
    _import static sun.misc.PostVMInitHook.run;_. And with it, it also doesn't work. It is just my fault to add it :)